# Puppet auditing of file resource not working

Tags: puppet

I just can't seem to get this to work at all. I want to have puppet send a log message that shows up in the reports whenever a file changes. This seems so simple from what I've heard and read, but nothing works at all.

Here is the init.pp file:

```
# sudo init.pp

# 21 Sep 2011: Changed to test for notification only

class sudo {
    package { 'sudo':
        ensure  => present,
        before  => File['/etc/sudoers'],
    }

    file { '/etc/sudoers':
        ensure  => file,
        mode    => 440,
        owner   => root,
        group   => root,
        source  => 'puppet:///modules/sudo/sudoers',
        replace => false,
        audit   => content,
    }

#   exec { "/bin/date":
#       cwd => "/tmp",
#       subscribe => File['/etc/sudoers'],
#       refreshonly => true,
#   }

#   notify { "sudoers has been changed.":
#       refreshonly => true,
#   }
}
```

If I add the `exec`, nothing happens. If I add the `notify`, it complains about the `refreshonly` parameter.

If I remove all of the options for the file except `audit`, then the file permissions change from 440 to 644.

If I remove `replace` then puppet overwrites the file.

My test has been:

1. Run `puppet agent --test`
2. Change file (`/etc/sudo`)
3. Rerun `puppet agent --test` (possibly with a `touch site.pp` or a `service apache2 reload` first)

I have yet to see **any** messages from `audit`. I'm running puppet v2.6.3 on Ubuntu Lucid Lynx server 10.04.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is very possible. What you need to use is the ["notify" metaparameter](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/stable/metaparameter.html#notify), which will tell the `file` resource to cause another resource to run if it is triggered. Some resource types care about being notified ("refreshed" in the documentation); `service` and `exec` resources are the most useful ones. You can then build an `exec` resource with `refreshonly => true` that writes to a log or to stdout.

I would implement your config above like so:

```
class sudo {
    package { 'sudo':
        ensure  => present,
        before  => File['/etc/sudoers'],
    }

    file { '/etc/sudoers':
        ensure  => file,
        mode    => 440,
        owner   => root,
        group   => root,
        source  => 'puppet:///modules/sudo/sudoers',
        replace => false,
        notify  => Exec["sudoers_changed"],
    }

    exec { "sudoers_changed":
       command => "/bin/echo '/etc/sudoers has changed...'",
       refreshonly => true,
       loglevel => "alert",
       logoutput => true,
   }
}
```

The `loglevel` and `logoutput` parameters to the `exec` will just make it more clear about where the output is going while you're experimenting; you can certainly tweak them to your needs.

Comment: This logs to stdout or to syslog; how do I log to the puppet logs? I assumed that `audit` would take care of this... Doing it this way keeps the info out of the puppet reports (which currently are mailed to important people).

Comment: Doesn't this also log a change each and every time puppet runs? Whereas, I thought an `audit` statement only logged a change when it happens.

Comment: Since the exec resource has "refreshonly" set to true, it will only run when it's triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to notify any type, so you can notify the notify type.

```
exec { "foo":
  notify => Notify["exec-alert"],
}

notify { "exec-alert":
  message => "sudoers has changed"
}
```

the fact that the file changes is logged to the puppet logs anyway, it's marked as a change.